# WPF Animated UserControl - Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, user-controls

In developing for my project I am trying to create a usercontrol element containing many canvas layers. It's a vector image imported with Blend. I created a .GIF model for the initial frame, and set a frame rate for each layer (40ms). In creating a .gif its to easy to control a frame speed for each layer. I'm now trying to make that motion in WPF using **Storyboard**, and to control appearance for each layer I'm using **Visibility** state like in my source code :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ProgressAnimation" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.0000000" Storyboard.TargetName="Layer1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4500000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames> 
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.1000000" Storyboard.TargetName="Layer2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4500000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>            
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.2290000" Storyboard.TargetName="Layer3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4500000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>        
   </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And of course I set a trigger :

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
       <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ProgressAnimationBeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource ProgressAnimation}"/>
     </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

Now the code works perfectly, but I truing do increase speed of the element, and got in trouble with that. Wen I set SpeedRation for my StoryBoard the element flashing/blinking and works very unstable.

Please help me to understand and learn a better method to do it right.